# Spacing for weighted limits

Tags: spacing

I'm naively trying to typeset a weighted limit using `\varprojlim ^W F`, but the output I get is the one on the right instead of the one on the left below.

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably obtaining the “Bad” line in the output below, but beware that, in display math mode that code would produce the “Ugly” line:

[image]

The “Good” line is obtained with

```
\varprojlim\nolimits^{W}\! F
```

and you certainly want to define a command for this:

```
\newcommand{\wlim}{\varprojlim\nolimits^{W}\!}
```

You might be tempted to say that the amount of back up provided by `\!` is too small: don't.

Comment: What do you mean "the two pictures show the same thing"? The FFF is much farther away in the right picture. I don't get the top line in your answer, I get exactly the bottom one, and I would like the FFF to be closer to the limit as in the left picture in my question.

Comment: @Arrow Try `\[ \varprojlim^W F \]` and you'll see where the W ends up printed. I'll edit.